# Impossible to serve generated images without restarting app with Rails + Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, passenger

I have images that are generated by users and written to `public/designer/designer_output` folder.

In `config/environments/production.rb` I have

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

In `config/initializers/assets.rb` I have

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('public', 'designer', 'designer_output')
```

Yet I can't access the files either by requesting `/assets/file_name` nor `/public/designer/designer_output/file_name`

If I restart the server then the files become available only via the `/assets/` path. But I need them to be available as soon as they are created without restarting.

If find it odd that I can't access them through the public folder at all.

This is on Rails 4.2.6 with Apache/Passenger

Also I have carrierwave as an upload gem, and it is storing files in public/uploads folder and that works fine.

Comment: Hi - can you please edit your question and add the actual code where you are accessing the images (rather than just describing the path you use)... sometimes the bug may be in how you are trying to access it - and we can't know until we see :)

Comment: I'm accessing them directly through those paths. Even if I have a bug on that side making a direct request should show the assets. Instead I get a 404. Plus, restarting the server make the images show, therefore the path is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public` folder is used as the web root for the rails server.
You need to drop `public` in the path or URL:

```
<!-- file is at /public/foo/bar.png --!>
<img src="/foo/bar.png" />
```

Comment: You should not use the Rails assets pipeline or the assets helpers for user generated files - thats not what its for.  The  assets pipeline is for developer generated content such as the images used in your CSS or images referenced by your views.

Comment: Thats why it requires a restart - assets are meant to be statically compiled when you deploy your application.

Comment: Yes, but then that's what the public folder would be for, right ? How come I can't access them in the public folder at all ?

Comment: Damn, sorry, I ready your answer a bit fast and thought you said add 'public' instead of removing it. It works now, thank you very much!

Comment: When you said I shouldn't use the asset pipeline for this, what does it mean exactly ? should i remove those paths from assets ?